# imag ldap bundle is checking ldap hostname & password before login in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, ldap, symfony-forms

I have used imag Ldap bundle for authentication in symfony2. But the problem is that it's checking the Idap arrtributes like ldap host name & password before submit the login page.
I didn't understand why it is checking before submitting the login form . It has to check the credentials when i submit the login form (ldap username & password ) at that time first it has to check for ldap hostname & password. But it is checking before submit the login form.

if any one know the solution regarding the problem .please help me because I need to fix the issue immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add in the section access_control of the security.yml:

```
security:
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

It allows to get the login form without to authenticate...